# get input value from localstorage array of object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

i have a localstorage with `cartproductx` key which contain array of object

```
[
{"id":"001",
"productName":"Tesla",
"categories":"car",
"price":1000000,
"quantity": 1
},
{
"id":"002",
"productName":"Honda",
"categories":"motorcycle",
"price":10000,
"quantity": 2
},
{
"id":"003",
"productName":"BMW",
"categories":"car",
"price":1200000,
"quantity": 1
}
]
```

then i make function to get value from `cartproductx[index].productName`and set to input value

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const carts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProductx"));

const GetData = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState(carts);

return (
<div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder=" product"
        value={data[0].productName} //Tesla
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="product"
        value={data[1].productName} //Honda
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="product"
        value={data[2].productName} //BMW
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
</div>
)
}
```

the problem is how to repeat input form and set value without hardcode one by one? and how to save the changed value into localstorage with the same key ("cartproductx")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over your state data and by using `id` you can use your `handleChange` function to make the changes.

```js
const carts = [
  {
    "id": "001",
    "productName": "Tesla",
    "categories": "car",
    "price": 1000000,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "productName": "Honda",
    "categories": "motorcycle",
    "price": 10000,
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "productName": "BMW",
    "categories": "car",
    "price": 1200000,
    "quantity": 1
  }
];

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(carts);


  function handleChange(e, id) {
    const { value } = e.target;

    setData((prev) =>
      prev.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== id) {
          return item;
        }

        return { ...item, productName: value };
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <input
          key={item.id}
          type="text"
          placeholder="product"
          value={item.productName}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, item.id)}
        />
      ))}
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.productName}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Also, I suggest using `useEffect` to read data from `localStorage` and use one more `useEffect` to set it again if you want to make the changes persistent.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const carts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProductx")) || [];
    setData(carts);
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cartProductx", JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data]);
  
  // rest of the code
```

Comment: how to save changed value intolocalstorage wiith same key (cartproductx)?

Comment: @deversekan dude.. you are my savior! thanks for your help